# Unable to find what's taking up so much space

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm having an issue in trying to figure out what's taking up so much space on one of my drives, specifically /dev/sdc1 which is mounted on /

As you can see below 862G are in use, I've used all methods I could think of to find the largest directories (excluding sdb1 and sda1) and all I can find is 19G on my Plex metadata folder. That's it... I need to figure out a way to find what exactly is taking up this amount of space as this just happened in the last couple of days after **sdb1** was unmounted due to a power outage, so it somehow "linked" or transferred files over there? Though I can't seem to find any... and have absolutely no idea how to go from here...

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a headless Odroid N2+

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           370M  6.3M  364M   2% /run
/dev/sdc1       938G  862G   29G  97% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk1p1   29G   10G   18G  37% /media/mmcboot
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  1.6T  108G  94% /mnt/hdd2
/dev/sda1       7.3T  6.8T  504G  94% /mnt/hdd
/dev/zram1       49M  4.6M   41M  11% /var/log
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Results of my search using

```
sudo du -hs .[^.]* | sort -rh | head -30

19G     .config
12M     .docker
56K     .bash_history
4.0K    .viminfo
4.0K    .profile
4.0K    .cache
4.0K    .bashrc
4.0K    .bash_logout
0       .Xauthority
0       .sudo_as_admin_successful
```

I tried `ncdu` as well and it shows:

```
   19.0 GiB [##########] /.config                                                                                                                                                      11.5 MiB [          ] /.docker
   56.0 KiB [          ]  .bash_history
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /Downloads
    4.0 KiB [          ] /.cache
    4.0 KiB [          ]  .bashrc
    4.0 KiB [          ]  .viminfo
    4.0 KiB [          ]  .profile
    4.0 KiB [          ]  .bash_logout
    0.0   B [          ]  .sudo_as_admin_successful
    0.0   B [          ]  .Xauthority
```

using `sudo du -xh -d 3 /  | sort -h -r | egrep -v '*K|*M'`

yields

```
109G    /
84G     /mnt/downloads
84G     /mnt
83G     /mnt/downloads/nzbget
19G     /home/sptz/.config
19G     /home/sptz
19G     /home
4.5G    /var
4.3G    /var/lib
4.1G    /var/lib/docker
1.5G    /usr
```

I'm guessing the above is excluding /mnt/hdd and /mnt/hdd2 aka sdb1 and sda1 right?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose one file system (say `/dev/sdb1`) should be mounted on `/dev/sdc1`, with mount point `/mnt/hdd`. Suppose, however, that the mount has failed. If some process still writes data to `/mnt/hdd`, it will end up on `/dev/sdc1`. If you subsequently mount `/dev/sdb1` successfully, this data is not accessible (because `/mnt/hdd` now points to the other filesystem) but it still takes up space. Could this be what has happened in your case?

Comment: Mount this disk from other system and run `ncdu` on it.

Comment: Jos, I believe this is exactly what happened. No idea how to fix it now :/

Comment: Please edit your question by adding what distribution you are on.  For example Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself: "`sdb1` was unmounted due to a power outage". This probably means that in this time, some data was written to `/mnt/hdd2` while `sdb1` wasn't mounted.

Unmount these devices:

```
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  1.6T  108G  94% /mnt/hdd2
/dev/sda1       7.3T  6.8T  504G  94% /mnt/hdd
```

And then check the directories for data (starting with `/mnt/hdd2`) - I believe there will be around ~750 GB of data here.

My guess is that data was written to one of these directories, where the disk wasn't mounted. This data now "disappears" when the drives are remounted.

This is only a qualified guess, but 99% of the time when data mysteriously disappears, this seems to be the issue.

Comment: This was it! I unmounted both those devices and there it was. 700GB of data in mnt/hdd.

I get the logic behind it but does this mean that if sda1 was mounted it's literally impossible to access those "hidden" files?

Comment: Yes. (-----------)

Comment: @Sptz87: There is a way, but it's not for the faint of heart: https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Shadowed-by-Mount.md

Comment: Yes, I believe a simple unmount, investigation and remount should be sufficient in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Install qdirstat
Run it as root by launching it from the Terminal/Konsole.

```
sudo qdirstat
```

Choose the root or home directory and then run it.
It will find where the stuff is.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a graphical software. My server is headless and have no way of connecting a monitor to it :/ There has to be an alternative

Comment: @Sptz87 not totally true, You can use it command linen and if you add this https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/tree/master/scripts you can use cron to do it every so often too